# Remove search box using sDom in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am trying to remove the existing `Search` box on top-right of the Table. And realign the `Show Entries` section at the bottom of the Table just below `Showing x of y entries`

I have used the following code.

```
"sDom": '<"top">tip<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
```

And it has mixed up the alignment at the footer completely.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Use the following value for `sDom` to display page length control at the bottom:

```
"sDom": '<"top">t<"bottom"ilp<"clear">>'
```

See [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) on `sDom` option for more details and explanation of `t`, `i`, `l`, `p` and other characters.

In order to display informational control and page length control on the left side, add extra CSS rules shown below:

```
.dataTables_info, .dataTables_length {
   float:left;
   width:auto;
   padding-right:15px;
}
```

#### DEMO

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bats7ej/) for demonstration.

Comment: can `showing x of y entries` be taken below `show x entries` using pure `sDom`?

Comment: @user2281858, try `"sDom": '<"top">t<"bottom"lp<"clear">i<"clear">>'`

Comment: works perfectly fine. I understand top, bottom stands for the div classes. Can you please explain what does `t, lp, i` stand for..

Comment: @user2281858, just updated the answer with more info.